# Issue on setting Sticky Div to Scroll to Top and Bottom

Tags: jquery, scroll

Can you please take alook at this [Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/Behseini/3fK5h/) and let me know how I can set the sticky div stays at the bottom of the viewport and also has ability to scroll page up and down when the second part of the page is in viewport. Here is a sample in [This link](http://www.realtor.com/). As you can see the

> `<div class="floating-bar evtFloatingBar"></div>`

is sitting at the end of page and controlling the scrolling of the page. Here is what I was trying to create:

```
<div id="first">Here is the First Part</div>
<div id="scroller">Click Me</div>
<div id="second">Here is the Second Part</div>

<script>
$('#scroller').click(function() {
    $('html,body').animate({
        scrollTop: $('#second').css('top')
    }, 800, function() {

        $('html, body').animate({
            scrollTop: 0
        }, 800);
    });
});
</script>
```

Thanks for you time